# navigate-to is Unimplimented. Are there any alternative

Tags: content-security-policy

The Content Security Policy navigate-to directive are not implementet.

https://content-security-policy.com/navigate-to/

Does there exist any alternative to block navigation to any external urls?
(Be it via A.href, window.open, location.replace)

It would give some extra security to admin systems that does not need any form of external links or navigation.

Best regards,

Anders